# Building custom Franka controller for visual servoing

Tags: ros, ros-control

[image: Rosanswers logo]

My goal is to control the Franka Panda system in cartesian velocity coordinates using vision data that is being published within my ROS network.

I'm currently writing a custom controller as recommended in Franka ROS:
https://frankaemika.github.io/docs/franka_ros.html#writing-your-own-controller

The cartesian velocity controller works well, but I have no method of subscribing to the input data since Franka ROS controllers are real-time.

What is the recommended method of achieving this? I saw somewhere that ROS controllers can host services, but this seems suboptimal. Do I have to implement a hardware interface? And if so, how I can write that to wrap a ROS subscriber?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/402921/building-custom-franka-controller-for-visual-servoing/) by [hmccarty](https://answers.ros.org/users/109213/hmccarty/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ended up using the `realtime_tools` package to solve this. You can use a `RealtimeBuffer` to pass data from your non-RT thread (like a subscriber callback) to a RT thread (like your controller update function). An example is detailed in the [ackermann steering controller](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/tree/noetic-devel/ackermann_steering_controller).

---

Originally posted by [hmccarty](https://answers.ros.org/users/109213/hmccarty/) with karma: 16 on 2022-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0